# Logstash : send logs using curl

Tags: curl, logstash

I have an ELK server to manage my logs. Generally they are send to automaticaly. All works fine.
But for some reason, sometimes, we need to send a log file.

I'm trying to do like this :

```
curl -F "file=@<my_file_path>" http://<ELK_server_host>:5001
```

And this conf (part that is usefull here) on the server side :

```
input {
    ...
    tcp {
        port => 5001
        type => "curl"
        codec => line { charset => "UFT-8" }
    }
    .....
}

filter {
    .....
    if "curl" == [type] {
        multiline {
            pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
            negate => true
            what => previous
        }
        grok {.....}
        date {.....}
    }
    .....
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        host => localhost
    }
}
```

This work really good **BUT** there is two little difficulties :

- The last (not empty) line of the file is ignored
- Curl command never stop. I have to kill with *Ctrl+C*.

Maybe this two points are connected but what is there a solution? Maybe the multiline filter is a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Part 1:**

It's hard to answer this without more information. But I'd expect the last line of your logfile doesn't end with a newline character? The logstash input codec "line" is looking for a newline at the end of each line.

To add one in Windows:

```
echo. >> path\to\your_log_file
```

**Part 2:**

cURL is made for talking to HTTP servers.  Logstash input "tcp" is not an HTTP server and doesn't send the HTTP response cURL is expecting at the end of the upload.

You'd be better off using a tool like [Netcat](http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows/) that is made to send data over TCP.

**P.S**

"UFT-8" looks like a typo.

Answer (score 5):

To properly support HTTP you need to add the following filter to your `input {...}` section:

```
http {
    port => "5050"
    codec => "json"
}
```

Then you can post JSON documents to port 5050 like a line from a tomcat access log.

```
{
    "message": "[20/Feb/2019:14:31:22 +0100] 10.3.249.128 - 200 \"GET /my/path/foo/bar HTTP/1.1\" 0 0 -",
    "fields": {
        "source": "access",
        "system": "dev"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you use logger command, it's better as it gives you more control over what you're sending:

```
logger  -t your_tag -p "local1.info" --file /path/to/file --server <ELK_server_host> --tcp --port 5001
```

Comment: I should have said that I want to send logs from Windows (Client). This command is available on Linux, right?